golang: HTTP redirect fails on poorly formed redirect location
I have a file download part of my system logic. The implementation is fairly straightforward - stock http package issuing a GET request and downloading the data via the response body.
On the server side, there is a 302 response with the Location field for the actual file URL. For files with simple naming it works pretty transparently - a single GET request takes care of the redirect and allows downloading the file. However, occasionally the actual URL (as specified by Location header) contains whitespaces (e.g. http://foobar.com/1234/quick brown fox.pdf) and this is where the normal GET logic seems to break - from what I see, the last URL requested is http://foobar.com/1234/quick which obviously results in a 400 error.
Given that I cannot change the server side to make those URLs well formed, what are my options? Is there a way to tell the http package how to manipulate the redirect or is my only recourse to implement the logic manually (intercepting redirects etc)?

Did you try using Client.CheckRedirect and see what the request looks like?url.Parse (and hence http.NewRequest) will automatically encode whitespace in the path.

I did. req.URL shows the URL with blanks. Maybe there is a way to transform the URL for redirects, so that I can URL-escape it?

So far, I've got it to work with a rather ugly workaround: I save the redirect URL (in CheckRedirect()) and - if I get a status code of 400 - I retry the download using that saved URL. It is not pretty, but it works. I hope, there is a better way...

I think you're going to have to dig a little deeper to figure at exactly what step your requests are getting broken. The Go http client will accept a Location header with spaces and correctly escape the path (there's no magic here, the client uses url.Parse to get the Location)
